# How to call a function using a shortcode

Tags: plugin-development

I want to display enrolled courses on a separate page using a shortcode to call the plugin function on the frontend. Which add_shortcode function do I use? Below is the function I am trying to call

```
$enrolled_course = tutor_utils()->get_enrolled_courses_by_user();
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1** Define your shortcode callback function. You can find some examples for generating the output [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/386787/how-to-render-complicated-shortcodes-inside-return/387294#387294).

```
function your_shortcode_callback( $atts ) {

    // if attributes as used with shortcode, then do something with $atts

    // get data
    $enrolled_course = tutor_utils()->get_enrolled_courses_by_user();

    // do something to turn the data into html string
    $output_html = '';

    // callback should return its output
    return $output_html;
}
```

**Step 2** Register the shortcode. The name can be anything you like as long as it is unique

```
add_shortcode( 'whatever_you_like_as_shortcode_name', 'your_shortcode_callback' );
```

**Step 3** Use the shortcode

```
[whatever_you_like_as_shortcode_name]
```

More details can be found in the [Shortcode API Codex entry](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

The shortcode callback and registering can be added to [a custom plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/) or to the theme's `functions.php` file.